# Получение hex из rgb

Tags: python, hex, rgb

Как я могу получить `hex` из `rgb` в   python?

Например у меня есть значение `rgb` - `255, 0, 0`. Как я могу получить значение `hex` из него?

Comment: `hex(r * 65536 + g * 256 + b)[2:]` например?

Comment: `print("#%02x%02x%02x" % (255, 255, 255))`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3380726/9210255

Answer (score 1):

```
'#' + ''.join(hex(int(i))[2:] if i != '0' else '00' for i in "255, 0, 0".split(', '))
```

Comment: `#ff00` выдаётся, а хотелось бы `#ff0000`

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> hex(reduce(lambda a, e: (a<<8) | int(e), '128, 19, 255'.split(', '), 0)).replace('0x', '')
'8013ff'
```

Answer (score 1):

вариант 1:

```
rgb = "255, 128, 64"

#text = '#' + ''.join([f"{int(i):02x}" for i in rgb.split(',')])

print(text)
```

вариант 2:

```
text = '#' + ''.join(map(lambda i: f"{int(i):02x}", rgb.split(',')))
```

Comment: вариант 2: #ff00 выдаётся, а хотелось бы #ff0000 ;)

Comment: :( дааааааааааа, я понял

Comment: да там вроде str не надо... hex и так отдает строку, а так просто копия моего ответа ;)

Comment: `'#' + ''.join(hex(int(i))[2:] if i != '0' else '00' for i in "255, 0, 0".split(', '))` ?

Comment: @Victor VosMottor, исправил первый вариант - теперь работает как надо

Answer (score 0):

```
r, g, b = map(int, "255,0,0".split(','))
hex(r << 16 | g << 8 | b)
```